# SQL query to copy a record

Tags: sql

How to copy records of one column of one table to another column of another table

```sql
SELECT vc.crm_id, vcd.deposit_id FROM visa_card_deposit vcd
INNER JOIN deposits d on d.id = vcd.deposit_id
INNER JOIN visa_cards vc on vcd.visa_card_id = vc.id;
```

I don't know now how to copy the records and transfer it to another column of another table

Comment: Please provide more details about your source and destination tables, and provide some sample data, and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You simply insert them:

```
INSERT INTO my_destination_table (my_destination_columns)
SELECT vc.crm_id, vcd.deposit_id FROM visa_card_deposit vcd
INNER JOIN deposits d on d.id = vcd.deposit_id
INNER JOIN visa_cards vc on vcd.visa_card_id = vc.id;
```